# How to replace same line within div element with another - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here I'm trying to display the number of lives the player has left after inputting a wrong letter like so:

[image]

However, when the player inputs a wrong letter the second time, it comes like this. I want the updated lives replaced in the same line.

[image]

Here is where I coded the livesCounter.

```
function livesCounter(){
    var lives = document.createElement('DIV');
    lives.innerHTML = "Lives Left:" + livecount;
    lives.id = "livesCount";
    hint.appendChild(lives);

    if(livecount<1){
        lives.innerHTML = "Game Over";
    }   
}
```

I tried to use inlineHTML like this, but it comes up empty.

```
function livesCounter(){
    var lives = document.getElementById('livesCount').innerHTML = '"Lives left:" + livecount';
    hint.appendChild(lives);
    if(livecount<1){
        lives.innerHTML = "Game Over";
    }   
}
```

And this is my full code:

```
//THE HANGMAN GAME 
var words = ['quaffle', 'bludger', 'pensieve', 'harry', 'lupin', 'butterbeer', 'polyjuice', 'patronus', 'horcrux', 'voldemort'];
var hints = ['A ball used in the wizarding game of quidditch thrown into one of the three goal hoops.', 'A ball bewitched to knock quiddich players of their brooms', 'A shallow metal basin used to review stored memories.', 'The boy who lived', 'The werewolf professor', 'A popular wizarding beverage',
    'A potion that allows the drinker to assume the form of someone else', 'A complicated and powerful defensive charm', 'An object used to attain immortality',
    'He Who Must Not Be Named'
];
correctletters = '';
missedletters = '';
livecount = 10;
counter = 0;



function getRandomWord() {
    randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    wordlength = randomWord.length;
    showHint();
    livesCounter();
}



function drawDashes() {
    elem = document.getElementById('lettercontainer');
    for (var i = 0; i < wordlength; i++) {
        var letterdash = document.createElement('DIV');
        letterdash.classList = 'dash';
        elem.appendChild(letterdash);
    }
}


function getGuess() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        letterGuessed = document.getElementById("inputfield").value.toLowerCase();
        document.getElementById("inputfield").value = null;
        alert(randomWord);
        r = randomWord.includes(letterGuessed);
        alert(r);

        if (r == true) {
            correctletters = correctletters + letterGuessed;
            alert("correct letters: " + correctletters);
        } else {
            missedletters = missedletters + letterGuessed;
            alert("missed letters: " + missedletters);
        }
        guess = missedletters + correctletters;

        replaceBlanks()
        displayGuessedLetters();
    }
}

function replaceBlanks() {
    for (var j = 0; j < wordlength; j++) {
        if (randomWord[j] === letterGuessed) {
            div = elem.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[j].innerHTML = letterGuessed;
            counter+=1;
            alert(counter);
        }

        else{
            livecount-=1;
        }

    }
}

function showHint() {
    hint = document.getElementById("hintcontainer");
    var wordIndex = words.indexOf(randomWord);
    hint.innerHTML = hints[wordIndex];
}

function livesCounter(){
    var lives = document.createElement('DIV');
    lives.innerHTML = "Lives Left:" + livecount;
    lives.id = "livesCount";
    hint.appendChild(lives);

    if(livecount<1){
        lives.innerHTML = "Game Over";
    }   
}


function displayGuessedLetters() {
    var content = document.createTextNode(letterGuessed);
    var container = document.getElementById("guessedletters");
    container.appendChild(content);
    guessedletters.style.cssText = 'font-family: "Josefin Sans"; font-size: 30px; text-transform: uppercase; color: rgb(255, 85, 49); letter-spacing: 20px';
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id = inputcontainer>
    enter a letter from <font color="orangered">A</font> to <font color="orangered">Z</font>:
    <form onsubmit="return false">
        <input maxlength = 1 id = inputfield onkeydown = "getGuess()" type="text">
    </form>

    guessed letters: <div id = guessedletters></div>

</div>

<div id = lettercontainer></div>

<div id = hintcontainer>
    <div id = livesCount></div>
</div>


<script>getRandomWord(); drawDashes(); replaceBlanks(); checkLetter()</script>
</body>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("livesCount").innerHTML = livecount`

Comment: That assumes that the element exists. @PrashantPimpale

Comment: yes posting an answer!

Comment: Then Prashant's comment will work. (I'd use `.textContent` rather than `innerHTML`).

Comment: Still no result. Could the position I called the livesCounter() function have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your livesCounter function is only appending each time it's called.  It should look to see if the element exists already, and based on that, either create the element and append, or simply update the html.

```
var livesCountDiv = document.getElementById("livesCount")
if (livesCountDiv != null){
   livesCountDiv.innerHTML = "Lives Left:" + livecount;
} else {
   var lives = document.createElement('DIV');
   lives.innerHTML = "Lives Left:" + livecount;
   lives.id = "livesCount";
   hint.appendChild(lives);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function livesCounter() {

$("#livesCount").remove();
var lives = document.createElement('DIV');
lives.innerHTML = "Lives Left:" + livecount;
lives.id = "livesCount";
hint.appendChild(lives);

if(livecount<1){
    lives.innerHTML = "Game Over";
   }   
}
```

you can try the above code using jquery

Comment: Tried it but nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `livesCounter` function as:

```js
var livecount=9;
var hint = document.getElementById("main");

livesCounter(livecount);

function livesCounter(livecount){
    var a = document.getElementById("livesCount");
    if(a)
    {
      a.innerHTML = "Lives Left:" + livecount;
    }
    else
    {
    var lives = document.createElement('DIV');
    lives.innerHTML = "Lives Left:" + livecount;
    lives.id = "livesCount";
    hint.appendChild(lives);

    if(livecount<1){
        lives.innerHTML = "Game Over";
    }   
    }
}


function myFunction(data){
livesCounter(data);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(1)">Test </button>
<button onclick="myFunction(2)">Test 1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(4)">Test 2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(6)">Test 3</button>
```